# wxpython: redirect text dynamically to text control box

Tags: python, wxpython, fortran

The sampled code below is for the GUI I am currently making. I have two problems. The first problem is when I redirect the python output using the `RedirectText` class, the output is printed on the TextCtrl box ('tc2') only when the loop is finished, for that particular iteration. How do I get the text to print as it goes through the loop and not when its finished?

My second problem is i'm using a compiled fortran file `EHSS_updated_atoms.out` the output from this file prints to the terminal and not to the text control box. How do I get the the output from the compiled fortran file to the text control box? as it is printed to the terminal.

```
import wx
class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self,aWxTextCtrl):
        self.out=aWxTextCtrl

    def write(self,string):
        self.out.WriteText(string)



def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

    self.InitUI()
    self.Centre()
    self.Show() 
    self.SetSize((800, 600))
    self.SetTitle('Hello')

def InitUI(self):
    import sys

    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    hbox5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Run prog')
    hbox5.Add(btn1)
    btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label='Stop prog')
    hbox5.Add(btn2, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, border=5)
    vbox.Add(hbox5, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.RIGHT, border=10)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.prog, btn1)
    #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cancel_prog, btn2)


    hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=(wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY))
    hbox3.Add(tc2, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
    vbox.Add(hbox3, proportion=1, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND,border=10)
    redir=RedirectText(tc2)
    sys.stdout=redir
    sys.stderr=redir


    panel.SetSizer(vbox)

def prog(self, evt):
    import os
    import shutil
    import subprocess
    from mobcal_prep import mobcal

    extension = '.pdb'
    list_of_files = [file for file in os.listdir('%s' % _selectedDir) if file.lower().endswith(extension)]

    prep = mobcal()

    for pdb in list_of_files:
        print '### Running PDB: %s ###' % pdb
        prep.new_mobcal_format(pdb)
        subprocess.call(['./EHSS_updated_atoms.out', pdb[:-4]+'_new_mobcal.mfj',pdb[:-4]+'_new_mobcal.out'])
        prep.caluclate_average('%s_new_mobcal.out' % pdb[:-4], pdb)
        subprocess.call(['rm', pdb[:-4]+'_new_mobcal.out'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with graphical interfaces, have into account that the program is basically running into a loop (the "main loop"), which among other things triggers events, etc. That's the main thread of the program. If you do anything inside that thread (like calling `EHSS_updated_atoms.out`) that blocks the main loop for a while, there will be no changes on your interface until that is finished.

You can make this work by, for example, running the `prog` function in a separate thread. Check [this forum post](http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/can-t-update-wxpython-ui-during-subprocess-623843.html) for a small example piece of code on how to do it. Note the hint to use `wx.Yield()` or `wx.SafeYield()` to make the interface more responsive.

Edit: forgot about the redirection.

You don't need to redirect the whole `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`. <strike>`subprocess.call` admits two arguments just for that, so if you pass `redir` to the `prog` function, you can do:</strike>

`call(.........., stdout = redir, stderr = redir)`

Edit:

For the redirection, try this instead:

```
p subprocess.Popen(['./EHSS_updated_atoms.out', pdb[:-4]+'_new_mobcal.mfj',pdb[:-4]+'_new_mobcal.out'],
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout:
    redir.write(line)
p.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help the wx.Yield works perfectly. I tried the "call(.........., stdout = redir, stderr = redir)" but I get at attribute error. AttributeError: 'RedirectText' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Comment: Mmmh... Ok. Then call expects a real file object, with C (low level) integer file identifier. The trick won't work. Let's see if we find something.

Comment: subprocess.Popen() is probably what the OP should be using instead of call().

Comment: That, combined with `subprocess.PIPE` for the redirection, yes. I was trying to find a way to still use some kind of pseudo-file object for the redirections, which would be nice.